# Fill in the boxes to get the right equation

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, no-computers, formation-of-numbers

Here is a math puzzle I had a little bit of hard time with

> [image: Blockquote]

No computers please

There is a solution without inverting 6 to 9

Comment: With regard to operator order on the left hand side, is the division performed first, followed by the subtraction and then the addition?

Comment: Yes  division before addition or subtraction

Comment: Glad you included the "no computers please" line :P

Comment: I can make a very close solution: $$25-12+12\:/\:3=6\times 3 \color{red}{-1}\tag{BODMAS or PEDMAS}$$

Comment: @DEEM Where does this puzzle come from, please?

Comment: can I put more than one number into the squares?

Comment: This is my own puzzle @Gareth McCaughan. My Grandapa told me!!

Comment: No more than one number in the square please @Oray

Comment: @DEEM I have already answered anyway ;) I presume it is the correct answer with your lateral thinking tag.

Comment: Yeah but there is another answer Oray

Comment: *There is no solution without inverting.* I proved it.

Comment: Whatever the intended solution, it had better be _clearly better_ than turning a 6 upside down.

Comment: (My guess: put more than one number in a box.)

Comment: @user477343 there is: I have just found one.

Comment: @WeatherVane really? Well, without lateral-thinking, it is not possible... but with lateral thinking does not necessarily mean inverting the $6$. So... I believe you :P

Comment: @user477343 as in my new answer. OP wrote there is a solution without inverting 6 to 9, therefore there had to be another way, but mine is not especially lateral.

Comment: @WeatherVane I saw it. Very nice :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The trick is that

> Two of the letters are actually roman numerals. D = 500 and C = 100. 
>  $25 - 12 + D / C = 3 * 6$ 
>  $13 + 5 = 18$ 
>  This uses all "numbers from below" once.

Comment: What a way to start as a new contributor!! Kudos @Usermomome. Great Lateral Thinking

Comment: Agreed with @DEEM. This is a beautiful answer; it's clear, does not break any of the given rules and makes perfect sense overall! $(+1)$, and welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (Puzzling.SE)**! :D

Answer (score 8):

## Partial Answer:

*This answer follows by BODMAS or BEDMAS or PEDMAS.*

---

Umm...

> **THERE IS NO SOLUTION!** (without lateral thinking; without inverting the $6$, for example)

Let's call the numbers we can choose from, the **Option Numbers**.

---

> 25 cannot be in the third and fourth box.

#### Proof:

> This is our equation: $$\Box-\Box+\Box\:/\:\Box=\Box\times\Box.\tag{$\small \rm given$}$$ $12$, $6$ and $3$ do not divide $25$, so the third box can only be $25$ if the fourth box is $25$. Suppose that involves a solution. Then we have  $$\begin{align}\Box - \Box + \boxed{25}\:/\:\boxed{25} &= \Box - \Box + 1 \\ &= \Box\times \Box.\end{align}$$

> The largest number for the left hand side is $25-3+1=23$ so the right hand side cannot be greater than $23$. But $23$ is prime and both $22$ and $21$ have two distinct prime factors (although none of option numbers are prime), so the RHS cannot be greater than $20$. 
>  
>  Also, $20=5\times 4 = 10\times 2$ which uses none of the option numbers as well, and since $19$ is prime, that means the RHS cannot be greater than $18$ which is $3\times 6$ or $6\times 3$. But also, every other product strictly involving the option numbers is greater than $18$, so the RHS cannot be lower than $18$ either. 
>  
>  If the RHS cannot be greater or lower than $18$, then it is equal to $18$. $$\Box-\Box+\Box\:/\:\Box=18.\tag*{$(3\times 6$ or $6\times 3)$}$$

> Now $18=6\times 3$ which uses two of the option numbers. So now we must find option numbers such that $$\Box-\Box+1=\boxed6\times \boxed3 =18$$ Therefore $\Box-\Box=18-1=17$. Of course the first box has to have a bigger value than $17$, because $17$ is positive and all the option numbers are positive. The only option number bigger than $17$ is $25$. So $\boxed{25}-\Box=17$. Therefore the second box has a value of $25-17=8$ but $8$ is not an option number. 
>  
>  This is a contradiction, so $25$ cannot be in the third box, and thus fourth one, too.

---

> $\Box\:/\:\Box=2$ or $4$.

#### Proof:

> Now $\Box\:/\: \Box$ has to be an integer since $18$ is an integer, therefore the numerator box (third one) has an option number greater than the denominator box (fourth one). Since $3$ is the lowest option number, then $3$ cannot be in the third box. That leaves $12$ or $6$, so that leaves the fourth box to be $6$ or $3$. Therefore, this fraction must be equal to $12/6$, $6/3$ or $12/3$ which is $2$, $2$ or $4$. And since $2=2$, then the fraction is either $2$ or $4$.

> We thus have the equations: $$\begin{align}\Box-\Box+2&=18 \\ \small{\rm or} \quad \Box-\Box+4&=18.\end{align}$$ Therefore, $$\begin{align}\Box-\Box&=18-2=16 \\ \small{\rm or} \quad \Box-\Box&=18-4=12.\end{align}$$

---

And finally,

> From the previous proof, **THERE EXISTS NO SOLUTION!**

#### Proof:

> Now considering the first equation, the first box has to have an option number greater than $16$. The only option number like that is $25$. We thus have $$\boxed{25}-\Box=16$$ therefore $\Box=25-16=9$. But $9$ is not an option number. That is a contradiction, so the first equation cannot exist. $$\require{cancel}{\xcancel {\Box-\Box=16}}$$

> Considering the second equation, the first box needs to be greater than $12$. It can't *be* $12$, it has to be *greater* than $12$. Again, the only option number greater than $12$ is $25$. We thus have $$\boxed{25}-\Box=12$$ therefore $\Box=25-12=13$. But $13$ is not an option number. That is a contradiction so the second equation cannot exist. $$\require{cancel}{\xcancel {\Box-\Box=12}}$$ But if both equations cannot exist, then...

> ...**THERE IS NO SOLUTION!**

---

Therefore,

> Some lateral-thinking *must* be required, unless you do not follow by BODMAS or BEDMAS or PEDMAS.

Comment: check the tags in the question :)

Comment: @Oray I did, but **DEEM** wrote that he/she found a solution *without* inverting a $6$ to a $9$, and I cannot think of anything else more lateral :P

Comment: @user477343 This is a great answer, and though I hate to do so, I can't help it because it's driving me crazy lol; your OOP is incorrect. [PEMDAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) is what you're looking for. Multiplication always comes prior to division.

Comment: @PerpetualJ That is not true, I think. MD and AS can swap either way. Say I have: $a+b-c$. What do you do first? Add or subtract? It is either way. Multiplication is literally adding a certain number of times (pun not intended) and division is subtracting a certain number of times, so it is either way for them too. See [here](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-PEMDAS-and-PEDMAS) for example :P

Comment: @PerpetualJ $ab\div c = (ab)\div c = a(b\div c) = ab(1\div c)$. There is more than one way to work around it. I guess PEMDAS sounds nice, though to be technical, it should be something like P E M/D A/S. Some users in [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) confirmed it :)

Comment: @user477343 Say for example I have $8 + 9 / 5 * 3 - 4$. Following **PEMDAS** I get $4.6$. Change the OOP to **PEDMAS** and you get $9.4$. The difference between the two can be substantial. I understand that you can follow **PEDMAS** on certain occasions and get the same answer; for example: $30 * 9 / 5 = 54$. However, if you throw addition, subtraction, or exponents into the mix, you can end up with the wrong answer. Not trying to give you a hard time, and I apologize if I overstepped.

Comment: Well, it depends on whether you are doing $9\div (5\times 3)$ or $(9\div 5)\times 3$. If it is the former, well, that is just equivalent to $(9\div 5)\div 3$ and the latter is equivalent to $(9\times 3)\div 5$. The brackets need to be there, and no, you're not giving me a hard time. I like math... a lot :P

Comment: Want to join [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83491/perpetual-riddles)?

Comment: @PerpetualJ yeah :D

Comment: This is such an impressive analysis @user477343. You must be an engineer :)

Comment: @DEEM xD I am no engineer (...yet). I am just a kid who likes math(s) :P

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be anything that says that only *one* number can be placed into each box.  Thus

> $$12 - 25 + 66 \div 3 = 3 \times 3$$

would be a valid solution.

It just requires putting

> two $6$s in the same box.

Comment: @Gareth I just saw your comment on the question above, *after* posting this solution.  I'm surprised you didn't post an answer yourself!

Comment: OP responded "No more than one number in the square please"

Comment: @Greg:  I'm only putting one number in each; I'm just putting one number *twice* in one of them...  :P   (This is a valid answer to the question as posed.  That criterion was not in the question.)

Comment: lol... I guess...

Comment: I didn't post an answer because I hadn't found (or indeed looked for) one :-).

Answer (score 4):

The puzzle explicitly states: **Each number from below must be used once at least once.**

Our numbers are $12, 6, 25, 3$. Without changing any of the numbers, using integer math instead of decimals, and following the rule above:

> $12 - 3 + 6 / 25 = 3 * 3$

Following [Order of Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations):

> $3 * 3 = 9$
>  $6 / 25 = 0$
>  $3 + 0 = 3$
>  $12 - 3 = 9$
>  $9 = 9$

Comment: ... Since when does 6/25 = 0. As a mathematician, I find this a ground breaking result XD I except a paper on ArXiv will follow shortly?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I stated that I was using integer only math. Integers are whole numbers and thus any decimal values are dropped. Hence 0.24 becomes 0.

Answer (score 3):

how about

> $25-9+12/6=3\times6$

to do that

> I rotated 6 into 9 as you suspected which is valid for the tag provided.

Comment: I didn't copy this - didn't notice - UV.

Comment: @WeatherVane  np :)

Comment: Happy that you reached the same conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is

> $25 - 12 + 25 / 3 = 3 \times 6$

because

> the numbers are octal base, and converting to decimal base

gives

> $21 - 10 + 21 / 3 = 3 \times 6$

Comment: I have already submitted this answer -.-

Comment: @Oray this is a new, different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the tag:

> Each number must be used.  It seems like there are 4 numbers: 12, 6, 25, 3.  However, I'm guessing there are 6 numbers (lateral thinking): 1, 2, 6, 2, 5, 3.  So one of the answers (there may be more with this logic): is
> 6 - 5 + 3 / 1 = 2 * 2
> 3 - 5 + 6 / 1 = 2 * 2 is another order